# Meaning of "high in reach" regarding a training session

Tags: meaning, phrases, idioms

If an educational company described their session methodology as "high in reach" does it mean:

1. the size of the audience
2. the effectiveness of the training
3. other?

The original sentence in a press release was just "Our trainings are low in cost, high in reach".

I see that this comparison with cost is sometimes being used together [for example](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2957672/) "*Our interventions must be high in reach but low in cost in order to most persuasively demonstrate worth in intervention*"

Comment: I don't know what that means, but from now on I'm only accepting high-reaching interventions.

Comment: It is not a commonly used term.  Just guessing from the context, it might mean broad in scope; giving you a lot of content for the money.  It could be purposely ambiguous so potential customers project their own meaning onto it.

Comment: *ambitious*....

Answer (score 1):

"High in reach" is a non-idiomatic way of saying that it *reaches* many people. This uses the word *reach* in the following sense:

> **reach** *noun*
>   2 The extent or range of something's application, effect, or influence.
>   ‘he told a story to illustrate the reach of his fame’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/reach)

Consider the fuller quote of the [link you provided](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2957672/) (emphasis, mine):

> When all is said, the promise of the history of diffusion scholarship and diffusion practice is a promise of efficiency in intervention: **Communicating** an innovation **to a special small subset** of potential adopters so that they, in turn, will **influence the vast majority of other potential adopters** to attend to, consider, adopt, implement, and maintain the use of worthy innovations. Our interventions must be high in reach but low in cost in order to most persuasively demonstrate worth in intervention.

It's talking about accessing a small group that would *reach* the larger (target) audience.

Answer (score 0):

It's a somewhat vague term, and can be interpreted in several ways.  But think of a person simply jumping to touch the highest point on a wall that they can achieve.  "High in reach" basically means challenging you to reach as far up as you can.

Answer (score -1):

"High in reach" in this context would mean the goals are high but within reach. It's a motivational phrase that you have high and lofty goals but with your abilities they are well within reach, or that you are well within your ability to meet those goals.

Comment: @Michael-Rader I'm sorry, but I think my question was ambiguous. I rephrased it. Your answer sounds more like from an attendee point of view.

Comment: Given your additional information I would still say it means what I wrote. Do you have an example of this being used? Is it ad copy? Is it referring to the workout type specifically or what? @macraf

Comment: Edited my question again.